# Shortening boost::function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, c++98, boost-function

When passing a `boost::function` as a parameter to another function (callback), this function's signature can become quite long.

**Example:**
Consider this `boost::function`:

```
boost::function<MyClass * (
      TypeA param1,
      TypeB param2,
      TypeC param3,
      TypeD param4,
      TypeE param5,
      TypeF param6)> CreateMyClass;
```

Now if we pass this `boost::function` as a function parameter, the signature, of the function using it, becomes horribly long and hard to read:

```
void myFunctionUsingTheCallack(boost::function<MyClass * (
          TypeA param1,
          TypeB param2,
          TypeC param3,
          TypeD param4,
          TypeE param5,
          TypeF param6)> the_callback);
```

Am I missing something here?
Is there any trick to shorten the signature of `myFunctionWithTheCallack`?

Comment: please specify which c++ version you are using

Comment: I'm using C++98. Tag added. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you `typedef` to a shorter name?

```
typedef boost::function<MyClass * (
  TypeA param1,
  TypeB param2,
  TypeC param3,
  TypeD param4,
  TypeE param5,
  TypeF param6)> Fun;

Fun CreateMyClass;

void myFunctionUsingTheCallack(Fun the_callback);
```

If you were using C++11 or above, you could use `using` instead of `typedef`:

```
using Fun = boost::function<MyClass * (
  TypeA param1,
  TypeB param2,
  TypeC param3,
  TypeD param4,
  TypeE param5,
  TypeF param6)>;
```

---

Instead of explicitly specifying the type you could also use a function template and let the type be deduced by the compiler:

```
template <typename Fun>
void myFunctionUsingTheCallack(Fun the_callback);
```

Comment: You should add the `using` version, just for completeness for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, on top of the two posted by @m.s. (use a concrete API to get the type):

```
// defined elsewhere:
void some_api(TypeA param1,
    TypeB param2,
    TypeC param3,
    TypeD param4,
    TypeE param5,
    TypeF param6);

using native_callback_t = decltype(&some_api);
void myFunctionUsingTheCallack(std::function<native_callback_t> callback);
```

Comment: that would require C++11 which *probably* is not available, otherwise why would the OP use `boost::function`?

Comment: @m.s. Some people use boost for everything and wonder why there is no `boost::vector`.